# Unexpected Behavior With Pthread, Barriers, and Sharing Array

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, barrier

I have a program which uses MPI + Pthread.  I'm stuck on implementing pthreads to share an array for read/writes.  I made mock code here, which mimics the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct args {
    double* array;
    int start;
    int stop;
    double myVal;
    double* row;
    pthread_barrier_t* barrier;
};

void* mythread(void* arguments){
    struct args* args_ = (struct args*)arguments;
    double* array = args_->array;
    int start = args_->start;
    int stop = args_->stop;
    double myVal = args_->myVal;
    pthread_barrier_t* barrier = args_->barrier;
    double* row = args_->row;

    for(int i = start; i < stop; i++){
        pthread_barrier_wait(barrier);
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            double a = row[j];
            int ind = i*10 + j;
            array[ind] = a + myVal;
        }
    }
}


int main(){

    pthread_t threads[50];
    int start_ = 0;
    double* array_0 = NULL;
    array_0 = new double[100*10];
    double* row = NULL;
    row = new double[10];
    pthread_barrier_t barrier;
    (void)pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, 50+1);

    for(int n = 0; n < 50; n++){
        struct args args_;
        args_.start = start_;
        args_.stop = start_ + 2;
        start_ = start_ + 2;
        args_.array = &array_0[0];
        args_.myVal = n;
        args_.row = row;
        args_.barrier = &barrier;
        (void)pthread_create(&threads[n], NULL, mythread, (void*)&args_);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        for(int k = 0; k < 10; k++){
            row[k] = i+1;
        }
        // usleep(100);
        pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
    }

    for(int n = 0; n < 50; n++){
        (void)pthread_join(threads[n], NULL);
    }
    

    // print
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            int ind = i*10 + j;
            std::cout << " " << array_0[ind];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Main spawns 50 threads.  Barrier is initialized with 50 + 1 (to include main thread).  This should sync all 51 threads on the pthread_barrier_wait() call, but the blocking wait call doesn't seem to allow the "row" array write loop to complete before releasing.

The expected result should be:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
.
.
.
.
.
.
etc.
```

The actual output is semi-random.  It completes the sequence in some threads, and in others it shows zeros, as if "row" never got filled in.  Adding usleep() after writing to "row" array doesn't help either - not that I can afford to have sleep functions in my code.  This leads me to believe I don't understand how pointer arrays are properly shared between threads.  I'm new to C++ so any help appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you create a `struct args` object, and then you pass the address of this object to `pthread_create`. The object is then immediately "destroyed" at the end of the loop iteration, and a new one is created at the next iteration, however, the newly created thread still has a reference to this old "destroyed" object.

You need to make sure that the object you pass to `pthread_create` persists long enough for either:

1. The thread to make its own copy of it
2. The thread to finish

As a very simple approach, you can instead move the declaration of `_args` to outside of the loop and turn it into an array like this:

```
struct args args_[50];

for(int n = 0; n < 50; n++){
    args_[n].start = start_;
    args_[n].stop = start_ + 2;
    start_ = start_ + 2;
    args_[n].array = &array_0[0];
    args_[n].myVal = n;
    args_[n].row = row;
    args_[n].barrier = &barrier;
    (void)pthread_create(&threads[n], NULL, mythread, (void*)&args_[n]);
}
```

The lifetime of `args_[]` is now longer than each of the threads. Alternatively you can dynamically allocate your `struct args` (e.g. with `new`) and consume the object in the thread (e.g. with `delete`). Or if you are using C++11 or later, you can use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::thread`, there is some documentation about how these two behave with each other [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).